# Django cache image from S3

Tags: django, caching, amazon-s3, memcached

OK I have a (simple) question:

I use `django-storages` and `boto` to serve static files directly from S3 (all `src` links are from S3). I work on apache, webfaction using memcached.
Now, in one of my templates I want to cache a large image. I do:

```
{% import cache %}
{% cache 86400 fragment_name %}
<img src="{% static 'img/large_image.png' %}" alt="" />
{% endcache %}
```

Every time I visit the page, the image is re-downloaded with the following response header:

```
Cache-Control: max-age=604800, s-maxage=604800, must-revalidate
Expires: Thu, 31 Dec 2099 20:00:00 GMT
Last-Modified: Wed, 27 Apr 2016 11:22:07 GMT
Server: AmazonS3
```

Shouldn't the image be cached the first time for 86400 sec and next time loaded from cache?

Am I doing something wrong or haven't understand something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Fragment caching

```
{% import cache %}
{% cache 86400 fragment_name %}
<img src="{% static 'img/large_image.png' %}" alt="" />
{% endcache %}
```

What you have here is django fragment caching. It has no influence on whether the image will be cached by the browser or not. Since the file is hosted on amazon s3, browser caching will be dictated solely by the meta data you set for the file object on S3.

Despite the marketing, template fragment caching provides very little benefit. It takes about as much time to connect to the cache and retrieve the data over the network as it does to render the template.

### Cache control headers

Looking at the headers for the image, it can be seen that the meta data `Expires` headers specifies that the file ought to be cached till 2099! However there is a conflicting `Cache-Control` header which dictates that the file should be cached only for 1 week. However since you want only 1 day of caching it wouldn't really matter.

```
Cache-Control: max-age=604800, s-maxage=604800, must-revalidate
Expires: Thu, 31 Dec 2099 20:00:00 GMT
Last-Modified: Wed, 27 Apr 2016 11:22:07 GMT
Server: AmazonS3
```

The headers that you have shown does not provide any conclusive evidence as to whether or not the file has been cached. That can be conclused by looking at the HTTP Status. If it is 200 the file has not been cached. However chrome developer tools sometimes provides wrong information on this. In that case the size field will show '[from cache](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/network)'

Comment: Thank you for your answer and sorry for the delay of my response. I was searching amongst various browsers and operating systems. My conclusion is that there is no public behaviour about cache handling. For example in Linux Mint Chrome, although the images are being cached (can see them inside `~/.cache/chromium/Default/Cache`), when I see the output of Developer Tools (Network Tab), all images have `Status Code:200 OK` (redownloaded). BUT when I test it with Windows 7 Chrome, all images have `Status Code:200 OK (from cache)`.

Comment: But there is, as I have explained caching is dependent on the headers sent with the image and browsers generally honour it.

Comment: I removed `Expires` header and rewrite `Cache-Control` to include only `max-age, s-max-age, public`. It it very pitty, in the year of 2016, to have this imbalance among different browsers and OS. Thank you for your thoughts and your answer, once more!

Comment: OK. I have found what went wrong. In my FF linux-mint, after `about:config` in the address bar, the `browser.cache.memory.enable` setting was True whereas the `browser.cache.disk.enable` setting was False. Once I set `browser.cache.disk.enable` to True, everything worked!

Comment: Glad to know it's sorted out.